# How to make bootstrap alert popup in another page when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Im trying to make an admin page where if i click on the button 'send', the message will be sent and there will popup a bootstrap alert on the employee page.
I have already the bootstrap alert setup, the message for the first time is shown. After I close and i send a message again i dont see any alert. I think it needs to be triggered when i click on the send button but im struggling about how to do that. Hope anyone can show me a simple way.
Here is the code for the admin page to send:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td>Send message</td>
                <input type="text" id="msg" name="Bericht"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form group">
                <button type="submit" id="sendButton"  asp-page-handler="Submit" >Send</button>
            </div>

        </tr>   
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

And here is the code for the employeepage where there should be a popup bootstrap alert from the admin page

```
<script src="~/lib/signalr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Start the connection.
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('/speedalarmhub')
    .build();


    connection.on('ReceiveMessage', function (message) {
                
                var encodedMsg = message;
                
                // Add the message to the page.
                
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = encodedMsg;
                
                

    });
    // Transport fallback functionality is now built into start.
    connection.start()
        .then(function () {

            console.log('connection started');
            connection.invoke('SendMessage');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error.message);
        });
</script>

<div class=container>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code for the Submit handler

```
public void  OnPostSubmit(NotificationModel notif)
        {
            DateTime datenow = DateTime.Now;
            CreateNotification(datenow, notif.Bericht);
        
        }


        public void CreateNotification(DateTime convdayid, string Bericht) 
        {

            
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();

            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            var sql = "INSERT INTO notification(bericht, datumnu) VALUES(@Msg, @Date)";
            using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Msg", Bericht);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", convdayid);
            
            

            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();  
        }
```

Comment: if you going to have some message pop up on a jump to a new page? Well, the current page rendering is terminated, and then the new page is rendered. once that page is created, it THEN travels down to the browser side. This suggests you have to set some persisting value (maybe session()) and then in the new page load event, the VERY last thing you do is inject your JavaScript to run + show the popup. You really can't trigger with client side code + server side code a client side popup or message in the current page since you leaving that page to another new page. So new page has to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im trying to make an admin page where if i click on the button 'send', the message will be sent and there will popup a bootstrap alert on the employee page.

To achieve your requirement of pushing notification to all connected users (employees) and then update client UI with received data, you can refer to the following code snippet to modify your project.

*inject an instance of `IHubContext` into admin page model class by adding it to your constructor*

```
private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;

public AdminPanelModel(IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
{
    _hubContext = hubContext;
}
```

*update `CreateNotification` method to push notification to connected clients*

```
public async Task CreateNotification(DateTime convdayid, string Bericht)
{
    //...
    //your code logic here
    //...

    await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{Bericht}");
```

Test Result

[image]

**Note:** *for more information about "Send messages from outside a hub", please check this doc:* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0